# How to merge image url in rails json response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rails-api

I want to send @survey image_url along with its attributes.How I send it

```
@survey_detail = @survey.as_json(:include => { :questions => { :include => { :options => {:only => :title } } } })
render json: {:success=>true, :message=>"Detail of survey",:survey=>@survey_detail}, :status=>200
```

Along with `@survey` other attributes I want to send @survey.image.url. I want to merge it with other survey attributes.

HOw I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can send how many attributes you want. Just add them like this :

```
render :json => {:success => true, :message=>'Your message', locals => {:survey =>@survey_detail, ....here you an add what attributes you want to send... }
```